# How to make a flowing ribbon background for iOS like the one on PS3?

Tags: ios, animation

I've started playing with animated background views in iOS, and I really think it improves the presentation of my app. However, I'd like to create a background that I don't know how to make. The effect I'm looking for is something like this:

activeden.net/item/green-ribbon-animated-banner-background/49229
http://i156.photobucket.com/albums/t34/pspelver/wallpaper.jpg

I'm not sure how to actually design the graphic for this kind of pattern, or if there is even a better way to do it with core graphics. Can anyone please advise? Thanks.

Comment: That is too complex to animate with Core Graphics and Core Animation.

Comment: Wild speculation follows: To me, the PS3 wave thingy looks like a Hough transform of some moving shapes. Knowing what they did with the PS2 clock graphics with the crystals, I'd guess it's the 4 playstation symbols moving and rotating run through a Hough transform to generate that graphic.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that can't be done with Core Graphics and Animation like qegal said, but you could try OpenGL?

Comment: Not sure. It probably doesn't have to be procedurally generated. For example, if you had a few of these "ribbons", and each one could be tiled horizontally, you could just scroll each one across the screen indefinitely at a different speed to get something very close. I'm just not sure how to actually make a graphic like that, though. Twisting a gradient in some way, but no idea how.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find (or create yourself) an animated image of what you want. You could probably just find or make a video of the effect you want and do a frame-by-frame change into something like a .gif. Then set that as your background. The problem I see with the effect you want is that it will probably take a lot of system resources.

Comment: I think swapping out a ton of frames like that would be more expensive than my comment above. This is really more of an artistic question than one about how to display or animate the background.

Comment: then try graphicdesign.stackexchange.com